# Output jbehave report to a different location other than code location

Tags: java, jbehave

I am trying to output the jebehave reports to a location(D:/abc) other than code location by,

```
URL url = null;
        try {
              url = new File("D:/abc").toURI().toURL();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
        }


.useStoryReporterBuilder(new StoryReporterBuilder()
            .withCodeLocation(url)                   
            .withDefaultFormats().withFormats( TXT,HTML));
```

However the jbehave/view folder gets created in D:/ drive and not in D:/abc folder. What could be the problem

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `CodeLocations` class to generate the URL;

```
.useStoryReporterBuilder(new StoryReporterBuilder()
        .withCodeLocation(CodeLocations.codeLocationFromPath("D:\\abc"))
        ...
```

I also replaced the slash with a backslash in the path.

Comment: I tried it but again the jbehave/view folder gets created in D:/ drive

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed that when using:

.withCodeLocation(CodeLocations.codeLocationFromPath("D:\\abc\\xyz"))
...

that JBehave will ignore the last listed directory in the path. So from the above path of "D:\\abc\\xyz" JBehave will instead write into "D:\\abc", ignoring the reference to 'xyz'.